# Basic Auth working in postman but it doesn't work on Flutter with dio even its same

Tags: flutter, authentication, http, basic-authentication, dio

I have a Basic Auth token. In postman its working as expected but when i try same thing with same header its not working on flutter dio. Why its not working ? How can i fix it ?

In Postman :

[image]

[image]

But when i try same thing in flutter with dio like :

```
 final Dio _basicAuthDio = Dio();
 String cred = "username:password";
String credEnc = utf8.fuse(base64).encode(cred);
_basicAuthDio.options = BaseOptions(
  baseUrl: "${ApiConstants.baseUrl}v2",
  headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", "Authorization": "Basic $credEnc"},
);
```

[image]

Its always giving me 404 error. Even data is same,endpoint is same, header is same. Why its happening ? How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you didn't forgot **api**/v2/... part. Is the same url showing up in request object details?

Comment: ohhh. I felt so stupid now. I was searching that error nearly like 2 hours. And you are right. I forgot to write it....